# In end-of-employment emails, why do people generally not mention their new employer?

Tags: communication, united-states, job-change

When an employee is leaving a company, it's common for them to send out a group email to other employees they know to announce their departure and to share non-work contact details (personal email, LinkedIn, etc.).

To me, it would seem natural in these emails to briefly mention your future employment plans - specifically, where you're moving to next (assuming you have a new job). I've been surprised to learn that this is actually quite *uncommon*. This I've learned from:

- Re-reading departure emails from people who left my current company for other companies, and realizing that they didn't mention their future employer (in all cases I knew the future employer from in person conversations).
- Looking at departure email templates online and seeing the vast majority don't mention a future employer.

I have two questions about this:

- Is there a reason why this is the culture?
- If I'm leaving my current company and I do mention where I'm moving to, will this be considered strange or rude?

Comment: Could someone explain their downvotes please?

Comment: `When an employee is leaving a company, it's common for them to send out a group email to other employees they know to announce their departure and to share non-work contact details` - It's probably not as common as you think, especially not in larger companies. `To me, it would seem natural in these emails to briefly mention your future employment plans` - Why? What purpose would that serve? Why would you want or need to tell people that?

Comment: It might also be considered to be in poor taste. When you break up with someone you don't tell all of their friends who your next girlfriend/boyfriend is do you? `"I wanted to let you all know that I broke up with Jennie and am now dating Becky. Give my best to Jennie when you see her."`

Comment: @joeqwerty - Or even more directly, writing directly to Becky: *Hey Becky. You are not drop dead beautiful (you're not even close), but Jennifer is. Besides, she's a lot more fun to be with, in all regards. Bye.* There's something to be said for not burning ones bridges.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**In short, because you're using a company asset to promote the workplace of a different company.**

Like you said in your post, you were aware of where your coworkers were going through personal conversations.  Which is generally just fine (though you don't want to stray into "Dude, you should check out how great it is over there - they still have openings, you know..." territory while in the office.

But any sort of farewell email?  You're sending it from your company email address.  You're sending it to employees of the company.  And you're sending it to their company email addresses.  That's a lot of company-centric stuff... which is why you don't want to be using that to essentially advertise a different employer - after all, if it wasn't better over at XYZ, why would you be leaving ABC to go there?

Instead, the purpose of those emails isn't personal (like you said, you found out the personal details from talking with them in person.)  It's to assist the company, letting employees know that any duties they were assuming you would be handling will need to be tackled by someone else.

Comment: Awesome answer! It never occurred to me to see it this way.

Comment: I've also seen where one person's profile within a company was enough to elicit other employees to follow simply because they believed that there must be something better for them at this other company as well.

Answer (score 6):

I think there are a few reasons. First, don't use your current company's internet and mail server to promote how wonderful another company is going to be and what you are going to do. That isn't professional in my opinion.

Second, why alert your current employer to your plans? It isn't their business. I tend to keep that information private from the company that I am leaving. You never know if there is a vindictive manager or HR rep in your current company who could make a call and attempt to thwart your future plans. This is the same reason that I never give permission or contact information to a prospective company to call my current company for a reference. My son made this mistake and his current boss gave him a bad review purposefully so the new company wouldn't make him an offer and he would thus stay put.

Business is business and it isn't anyone's business where you are headed. If you have colleagues that you are friendly with, you can tell them in person and provide your personal contact information if you like.

Comment: Yep - I knew for a fact that I'd have a vindictive manager (his behavior when I gave notice and the days following made that very clear), and since I was still an H1B visa beneficiary I wanted to make it as difficult as possible for him to throw a wrench in my transfer plans. Not knowing where I was going with any more detail than this City in that State made it more difficult for him.